# Saving Blender Files Issue

Tags: workflow, file-format, blend-files

I am not sure if it's a bug or something but blender have saving issues, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save blender file,

[image]

the file saves not in blender format,

[image]

so every time I have to remove the **1** from the format in the end and add it to the title.

**My Question is: Can I somehow fix this and Save without the need to press** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: I think that is a versioning system built into blender [See Ref](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?325527-Why-does-blender-save-multiple-files-blend-blend1-blend2)

Comment: read the manual page for versions (http://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/save.html?highlight=save%20version)

Comment: "*read the manual page for versions*". That's just the kind of answer I don't expect to see on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.blend1, .blend2,... are the auto-backup versions of your last saved file (see in user preferences/File "save versions"). .blend is the current version.

Comment: Can I somehow change it, for it to add number 1 to the end of the file NAME not the format ?

Comment: WHAT is the problem to deal with OS ? And to tell *it* to open files with extension .blend1 with the same program as is being done for those .blend ones, instead of trying to change writing files process?