# Where does MyProject 2.blend come from?

Tags: blend-files, saving

When I've been working with `MyProject.blend` for a while, I see several files in the directory where I saved it:

```
MyProject.blend
MyProject.blend1
MyProject 2.blend
MyProject 3.blend
MyProject 4.blend
```

Blender *also* has stuff in `/tmp`

I understand that `MyProject.blend1` is from the "Save Versions" setting in User Preferences.  And I gather the Blender should be autosaving to `/tmp` (which is set as my temp directory in User Preferences).

But where do the `MyProject 2.blend` and `MyProject 3.blend` and similar automatically created files with an extra number in the name come from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender saves a new file every time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/blender-saves-a-new-file-every-time)

Comment: Also related: [How do I get blender to stop creating so many files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61223/how-do-i-get-blender-to-stop-creating-so-many-files), [Saving Blender Files Issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35667/saving-blender-files-issue), [Config blender to save backup files in subfolder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/config-blender-to-save-backup-files-in-subfolder)...

Comment: @brockmann That other answer talks about the `MyProject.blend1` file, but doesn't answer my question about the `MyProject 2.blend` file